# Need functionality of smart-Guides in Angular like jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable, ui-guidelines

I need the use of smart guides and multiple drags with angular2-draggable library in my one project. This will be a great help for my work.

For this, I am attaching a link to jQuery Way. A directive with smart guides and multiple drags will be of great support.

Link: - [Jquery Smart Guides](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/drag-resize-smart-guides.html)

[angular2-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-draggable/v/2.1.5)

I had attached this jQuery Library in my code and it's attached as well. Now I need the events which are used in this library in project. These events are conflicting with the current work.

Now any help is appreciable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.